# Will Unity be the only interface for 11.04?

Tags: unity, 11.04, gnome, 11.10

Will the Unity interface be only be default for the 11.04 or until GNOME Shell is released? Or alternatively will Unity continue to be developed after GNOME Shell is ready.

Simply: will 11.04 be a one-off release in having the Unity interface as default.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking - could you possibly re-phrase your question?

Comment: As a housekeeping thing: the title of this question does match the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody knows for sure, but it seems highly likely. From what Mark Shuttleworth (founder of Ubuntu) said today it sounds like there is a push for polish towards the next LTS release. Based on that it seems highly likely Unity will be kept as the default interface until at least 12.04

Comment: i very much agree.

Answer (score 7):

As things stand today, every foreseeable Ubuntu release until the end of the GNOME 3.x series will feature GNOME 3.x, minus GNOME Shell. GNOME Shell is just one part of the GNOME stack.

This is GNOME Shell:

http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/

This is GNOME 3:

http://live.gnome.org/ThreePointZero

Answer (score 5):

As in Ubuntu 10.10 (and 10.04), GNOME Shell will be available to install, and should be a first-class citizen.  The existing “GNOME 3” session you can select from the login screen will remain, and will continue to provide a close to standard upstream GNOME Shell experience.

So, while Unity will be the *default* experience, it will remain easy to use GNOME Shell (or the existing traditional 2D desktop) instead.

Answer (score 2):

My answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9861/will-unity-be-the-only-option-during-install) can probably help clear this up for you.

Answer (score 1):

They are changing for Unity because they "don't like the way Gnome Shell is taking". I don't think that they will be coming back to it if that's what they think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that will be consider at future UDSes. The Ubuntu devs will always consider what development have happen to make Ubuntu the best distro it can be.

Answer (score 0):

there are no info yet but it is confirmed that Unity will be default for desktop editions in Ubuntu 11.04 =)

Sources : Webupd8

Answer (score 0):

I think not "only". Ubuntu 10.04 LTS I can say best version. So... there are and there will be a lot of versions (10.04, 10.10) to use... I think it is OK about default interface 11.04, even next versions :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems they'll drop GNOME Shell and switch also the Desktop version to Unity.
See [this article on Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2010/10/shuttleworth-unity-shell-will-be-default-desktop-in-ubuntu-1104.ars).

Comment: I believe the question asker is well aware of this. That article refers to release 11.04. The question is what will happen after 11.04, e.g. 11.10?

Comment: @fluteflute I know, but i doubt in 6 months they'll go back again ti GNOME.

Comment: I don't see why this answer is getting negative votes. It seems clear to me in the article that Ubuntu Desktop will go for Unity instead of Gnome Shell and I don't see why they would implement Unity in 11.04 to go back to Gnome Shell in the following release. They are looking for a unified experience between UNE and UDE, so such a move would be totally counter productive and not user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

No. 11.04 will also have KDE, XFCE, etc. just as previous releases have.