# Will you have option to remove Unity in 11.04?

Tags: gnome, unity, 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Unity be the only option during install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9861/will-unity-be-the-only-option-during-install)

In the new release of 11.04 will you have the option to uninstall Unity and go back to the normal Gnome desktop?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question is asking whether Unity is the only option **during install**. This question is asking if it is possible to remove at all.