# Current GNOME Interface in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: gnome, unity, 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Unity be the only option during install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9861/will-unity-be-the-only-option-during-install)

I am wondering if it will be possible in Ubuntu 11.04, to use ordinary (the current) GNOME interface like the one in Ubuntu 10.04, because I don't really don't like the Unity look.

Thank you.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate (not of that question anyway). It's asking if Unity is the only shell available on Natty. The other asks if Unity is only for 11.04 (or if it will be replaced). I for one would like an answer to *this* question as I hate the idea of Unity.

Comment: Just to clarify @Shark, your question is about using the "current" GNOME interface, rather than the upcoming GNOME Shell?

Comment: @fluteflute I am asking if the future Unity desktop interface could be changed to current Gnome interface. In other words - would it be difficult to "hack" Unity interface to personal whishes (e.g. current Gnome interface).

Comment: I've just edited your question to clarify this - and hopefully your question will be reopened soon. :)

Comment: My answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/9861/will-unity-be-the-only-option-during-install

Comment: @Jorge Castro Thanks. I consider my question answered.