# Will there be a derivative with GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, 11.04

I just wonder, will there be a separate version with GNOME desktop (GNObuntu/Gbuntu or something)? I think there are many users including me who like GNOME. Please don't take GNOME away from us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Current GNOME Interface in Ubuntu 11.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10075/current-gnome-interface-in-ubuntu-11-04)

Comment: Ubuntu will continue to use GNOME in all of the foreseeable future versions.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe, as the other questions deal with using -shell as part of the installer, this is question is about a standalone ISO.

Comment: I think there might, considering that there is a Kubuntu.

Comment: not a duplicate.

Comment: It looks like Gnome will be an option in 11.04.  On this site it says if users don't want Unity, then traditional GNOME will be "provided". It doesn't say if it will be an option in the installer, or just through the software center.            http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/desktop-unity-your-questions-answered/

Answer (score 3):

Unity is simply an interface, Ubuntu will still use GNOME. You will be able to install GNOME Session on the Software Center, and choose beetween Unity and GNOME Environment (or something like that), as you do now if you install unity on your ubuntu-desktop.
The same will happen when Gnome-shell will be released, you will be able to install a Gnome-Shell session.

Comment: I mean, it's not as you install kubuntu-desktop on your Ubuntu. They will be a few interface package.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no seperate ISO that will be a pure upstream GNOME 3 experience. You can check the [derivative team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeTeam/) wiki page for information on how to create your own.

Comment: What Jorge means (I think) is that there might be a derivative .iso if there are enough people who volunteer to maintain it.  ;-)  In that respect it would be on the same level as Xubuntu or Edubuntu for example.

Answer (score 0):

As other said, Ubuntu still use GNOME, Unity it's only a replace for GNOME Shell.. Also you can install the traditional GNOME session at Ubuntu 11.04 ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an unofficial derivative called the [Ubuntu GNOME Shell Remix](http://ubuntu-gs-remix.sourceforge.net/p/home/).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so, but you will have the possibility to run gnome instead of unity

Comment: There is no 'GNOME instead of Unity'. Unity is a shell for GNOME.

Comment: i was just trying to be clear