# Unity stopped working after zeitgeist uninstall

Tags: unity, zeitgeist

In previous question I asked how to disable zeitgeist [Disabling Zeitgeist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45548/disabling-zeitgeist/45549).

After I removed all packages, I was unable to find anything via unity launcher! Shortcuts to media apps, internet apps...dont work.

Reinstalling zeitgeist didnt help.

Any idea how to recover unity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed by installing unity add-ons: unity-place-applications and unity-place-files.

I can call this a bug: uninstall zeitgeist, install zeitgeist and you lose unity application and place files add-ons. They should be independent.

Comment: They shouldn't be independent at all... it's how they work :). If you don't like zeitgeist logging what you do, just blacklist "*".

Comment: I must dissagree. unity-place-application is something like gnome application menu, right? Why should it need a zeitgeist? Why "Media Apps" button stopped working. Don't tell me that is not a bug. It should work, but not showing recent applications. Instead that, it was uninstalled, and ubuntu software center didn't notify me that this 2 addons will be removed from unity.

Comment: @umpirsky - unity-place-application is NOT supposed to work *that much* like GNOME Menu. It does more than just blindly list applications. So, it is NOT a bug. The "bug" here is that you wanted to remove zeitgeist (and I told you how; and you got your wish) - but obviously all actions have consequences. If I had known that: 1 your were using unity | 2 you wanted the functionality; I would have told you not to do that. :)

Comment: @Roland Hm, so Unity need zeitgeist to: 1. Be able to respond to Ctrl+F2 to run command 2. Be able to respond to click event on buttons: "Media Apss", "Internet Apps", "More Apps"... 3. search installed applications, files and folders. All in all, Unity Launcher does not work at all without zeitgeist (except you can click on 4 icons web (ff), photos, email and music (bashee)).

Comment: there you go...

Comment: Don't you think that is unnecessary dependency?

Comment: uh, no, actually.

Comment: So you think that Unity needs zeitgeist to tell him what applications are installed on system?

Comment: The applications are sorted by usage, so it makes sense to use zeitgeist in the back. I do understand you totally though …

Answer (score 3):

Run `unity --reset`. You will lose all of unity's settings, but at least it should start working again.