# Unity Dash "Most Frequently Used" Application Disappeared, How to Reinstall Unity & Zeitgeist Completely?

Tags: 11.04, unity, unity-dash, zeitgeist

My "Most Frequently Used" Applications in Unity Dash disappeared.

I tried to:

- reset unity with **unity --reset**,
- removing Zeitgeist history with **rm ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite**, and even
- reinstall zeitgeist via Synaptic,

but no one worked.

I also used Guest Session to check whether it only disappeared in my account, but actually not.

I don't know why it happened. How can I get it back?
How do we reinstall unity and zeitgeist so that they really return to the state as when they are freshly installed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly similar: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45560/unity-stopped-working-after-zeitgeist-uninstall . 
It suggests re-installing unity-place-application and unity-place-files.

Comment: @jgbelacqua Thanks, but I found that the problem is actually with zeitgeist config files in **~/.local/share/zeitgeist**. I don't know exactly what files, but deleting the whole folder and generating a completely new one does the trick ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, found the solution myself ^^

I had another problem with file search, and tried to completely remove and reinstall the components of unity and zeitgeist many times but it didn't help. So I tried something else and found the solution.

Simply delete the `~/.local/share/zeitgeist` folder (not just `activity.sqlite`), and restart the computer. It will generate a new and fresh zeitgeist folder, and the dash will be normal again.

Note:
Just for safety reasons, I chose to rename the zeitgeist folder to zeitgeist.bak instead of completely deleting it, in case things didn't go as intended, because this was actually just a **trial and success** attempt :)

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem for me. Any ideas what else I can do?

Comment: @Valorin Have you come across any other possible solutions?  Aside from removing `~/.local/share/zeitgeist` or reinstalling `unity-place-application` and `unity-place-files`?