# Will Ubuntu 11.10 feature GNOME Shell?

Tags: unity, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [will the unity interface be only for 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9432/will-the-unity-interface-be-only-for-11-04)

Will 11.10 feature GNOME 3 / GNOME Shell or will it feature Unity forever?